# Cannot access DOM with server-side render - react 0.14.1, react-dom 0.14.1 and react-router 1.0.0-rc3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I can't access the DOM with server implementation of react, react-dom and react-router.  I either have ReferenceError: document is not defined, or Browser history needs a DOM errors.

Server entry:

```
module.exports = function( req, res, next ) {
  match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (error) {
        res
            .status(500)
            .send(error.message);
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
        res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
    } else if (renderProps) {
        res
            .status( 200 )
            .set( 'Content-Type', 'text/html' )
            .send( '<!doctype html>' +
                renderToString(
                    [ <RoutingContext {...renderProps} />,
                    <HtmlDocument /> ]
                )
            );
    } else {
        res
            .status(404)
            .send('Not found');
    }
  })
};
```

client.js:

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import routes from './routes';

render( routes, document.getElementById('app') )
```

routes.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';

import Application from './Application';
import Index from './pages/index';
import App from './pages/app';
import Auth from './pages/auth';
import Login from './pages/auth/components/Login';
import Signup from './pages/auth/components/Signup';
import NotFound from './pages/notFound';

var routes = (
  <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
    <Route path="/" component={Application}>
    <IndexRoute component={Index} />
        <Route path="app" component={App} onEnter={ App.requireAuth } />
        <Route path="auth" component={Auth} />
            <Route path="signup" component={Signup} />
            <Route path="login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);

export default routes;
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: This might help https://github.com/DominicTobias/universal-react/blob/master/app/Router.js

Comment: Awesome Dominic, thank you that's been super helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [React Router server rendering guide](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/server-rendering.md) again. You only render the `<Router>` with browser history on the client; on the server, you just pass the *routes* (but not the `<Router>`) to the `<RoutingContext>`.

Comment: That's fixed the DOM error, but renderProps in the match callback returns null now for the routes I include. Any ideas there?

Comment: Which error condition are you hitting? Make sure the URL you have actually matches the routing configuration you have. Try making sure things work with just the client-side routing first.

Comment: Was importing the routes incorrectly into the file- getting the match working now. Thanks.

Comment: @almccann would you care updating your question (or adding an additional answer) with the approach that finally worked for you? The question would become more useful to Googlers this way.